# How to fix tar/gzip files after change extension?

Tags: linux, bash, compression, zip, tar

I am new in linux. Today I got issue.Then I run tar to zip multiple files(hundreds files) I got a.php.gz,b.php.gz,etc. After that I rename files via command line `find /usr/local/var/www/html -depth -name "*.php.gz" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.php.gz}.php"' _ {} \;`.
But now when I open PHP file it be encoded I cant view file. So Anybody have way to fix that?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Compressed files aren't text files, and so they can't be easily edited in text editors. Renaming the files doesn't change their contents or format; having an extension `.php` doesn't make them php files.

I'm guessing that you were trying to use gzip compression for your site's files when they're served over the web. For that, you don't need to compress the files manually like you seem to have done. The web server you will be using (say, Apache, nginx or the like) will have configuration options you can set to enable compression, which will make the servers compress the files automatically as appropriate when requested over the web.

Comment: This article seems to give some basic background and instructions: https://blog.hubspot.com/website/gzip-compression